# How to draw trails when moving a picture box in C# WinForm project

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner currently working on a personal project. I've managed to move a picture box using the W,A,S,D keys. What I wanted to do next is for my picture box to leave a trail wherever it moves, and erase the trail when it goes over them (kind of like pacman)

The trails can either be a line, or bunch of dots. I've tried by drawing new rectangles as the trails, but it won't work. Like I said, I'm a beginner :)

Here is what I have so far :

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, PaintEventArgs a)
{
    int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
    int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) y -= speed;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= speed;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += speed;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) y += speed;

    Collision(new Rectangle(x, y, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height), pictureBox2);
    Collision(new Rectangle(x, y, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height), pictureBox3);


    if (movement == true)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
}

private void Collision(Rectangle rect, PictureBox b)
{
    if (rect.IntersectsWith(b.Bounds))
    {
        movement = false;
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    movement = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to frame your question assuming that the community here knows nothing about your project. Explain what you've done, what is wrong, and how you've tried to fix it. Include any relevant code so we can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: how is this trail suppose to look like? a bunch of dots? a line?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post.
bunch of dots or lines are fine either way, honestly.

Comment: "'ve tried by drawing new rectangles as the trails, but it won't work. " you need to be more precise in the problem description. What was the outcome? what does "won't work" mean exactly?

Comment: "you need to be more precise in the problem description. What was the outcome? what does "won't work" mean exactly?"

It won't draw. I guess it might be a logic error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a history of the `(x,y)` positions of the picture box in order to use them for drawing at each `Paint` event.

When the form redraws it clears the client area (window) using the background color and draws the controls. Additional, you can hook into the `Form.Paint` event and do additional drawing before the controls are drawn.

For your solution, I suggest you have a `Queue<Point>` object where you can add the location after each movement, and remove old locations once the list reaches a certain limit.

As far as drawing, first read some [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/custom-control-painting-and-rendering) on how it works.